# Direct3D 11 FreePascal Create Device

Tags: directx-11, freepascal, fpc

I have just want to test direct3d 11, but it crashes at
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain call with error message project raise exception class 'external: ?' at address. Video Card supports Directx 11.
What is wrong?

```
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( nil, g_driverType, 0, createDeviceFlags, @featureLevels, Length(featureLevels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, sd, g_pSwapChain, g_pd3dDevice, g_featureLevel, g_pImmediateContext );
```

Comment: I never heard of "FreePascal", but you should be looking at the debug output stream and examining all `HRESULT` values returned by Direct3D functions and methods to see the specific cause of the failure.

Comment: Solved with disabling FPU exceptions